# Rails caching on Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On Production I have caching switched off in config/environments/production.rb:

```
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

However content is being cached and I can't seem to clear it. The log just states:

```
Started GET "/1234" for 12.34.56.78 at 2013-06-21 23:36:41 +0100
Processing by MyController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"product_id"=>"1234"}
Rendered my_app/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 259ms (Views: 2.1ms | ActiveRecord: 254.7ms)
```

What gives and how do I clear the cache?

Comment: Are you doing page caching? If so, I think you need to delete cached files in /public.

Comment: The only files in public are: 404.html  422.html  500.html  assets  favicon.ico  robots.txt  system

Comment: Why do you think caching is occurring?  As @cpuguy83 mentioned, there is no caching here.  Is it because there are fewer lines in the log file output?  Production Rails configures the logging level to 'Info' instead of 'Debug', so all the logging.debug lines will produce no output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not doing caching at all.  And setting action_comtoller caching to false truly ensures that no caching is done.

If there was caching your response would literally say that it was loaded from cache.

Comment: Completely correct. There was no caching going on. I'm using Passenger and needed to run `touch tmp/restart.txt` to tell it to restart.